# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Softprodigy_Multipleaddtocart_Helper_Data' not found in /html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: xml, magento-1.9

A bit of background -- We didn't start noticing this error until after we upgraded from Magento 1.7 to 1.9. After the upgrade this error message would occur throughout our system.log but showed no sign of causing a significant problem on the front-end until we tried creating new admin panel **user roles**.

The system.log would report:

```
2015-12-09T16:50:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Softprodigy/Multipleaddtocart/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/chroot/home/xxxx/xxxx.com/html/app/code/local:/chroot/home/xxxx/xxxx.com/html/app/code/community:/chroot/home/xxxx/xxxx.com/html/app/code/core:/chroot/home/xxxx/xxxx.com/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /chroot/home/xxxx/xxxx.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Inside **app/code/local/Softprodigy/Multipleaddtocart/Helper** we find Data.php with proper permissions and unedited, original code from the vendor.

### **Logging into the Magento Admin Panel**

**System > Configuration**

We see the Softprodigy label with the Multicart Products tab on the left-side navigation bar.

**System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced**

A [Sanity Check](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/#sanity-check-is-the-module-enabled) shows the inclusion of this Multipleaddtocart extension. Enable/Disable seems effective for both the global and granular scope.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the XML structure of the Softprodigy_Multipleaddtocart module.

Open config.xml from **app/code/local/Softprodigy/Multipleaddtocart/etc/** and you should see

```xml
<config>
<modules>
    <Softprodigy_Multipleaddtocart>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </Softprodigy_Multipleaddtocart>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <multipleaddtocart>
            <class>Softprodigy_Multipleaddtocart_Block</class>
        </multipleaddtocart>
    </blocks>


    <helpers>
        <multipleaddtocart>
            <class>Softprodigy_Multipleaddtocart_Helper</class>
        </multipleaddtocart>
    </helpers>
```

Our error log shows we have a helpers issue so lets focus on just that.

```
<helpers>
    <multipleaddtocart>
        <class>Softprodigy_Multipleaddtocart_Helper</class>
    </multipleaddtocart>
</helpers>
```

We need to change `<multipleaddtocart>` to the `<companyName_moduleName>` naming syntax (lowercase by convention) for Magento to be able to properly identify our new helpers class.

Our final bit of code should look like the following.

```
<helpers>
    <softprodigy_multipleaddtocart>
        <class>Softprodigy_Multipleaddtocart_Helper</class>
    </softprodigy_multipleaddtocart>
</helpers>
```